# In SharePoint Online-How to Get the File Path for a CSS Class in Firebug

Tags: sharepoint-online, css

I am trying to modify the background color for one of the CSS Classes so that the "Feedback" Button on the bottom right hand corner gets hidden. On the Firebug Tool, Instead of listing the File where the class resides, it shows something like this **viewlst..view=14 #28 (line 1)** . How do I get the File Name and the Path. Once I do a right click on this url and copy link location I get this https://xx.sharepoint.com/sites/xx/_layouts/15/viewlsts.aspx?view=14

Kindly suggest on how I can find the Path and the File Name for the class

**Update**

I tried the same in Internet Explorer.There is no File Name
[image]

Comment: Are you tried to use Developer Tools at IE ?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get your custom CSS file URL , try to open your page  Via Internet Explorer .

- Click F12 to show Developer Tools.
- Use select element > Select the control> at style section > mouse over the CSS file name it will show the CSS file URL place.

[image]

Also, You can do this without going to the CSS file (in case of, it's  a built-in system CSS file like `corev15.css`)

- Open your page in Browser
- Edit Page
- Add script editor

Add the following style

```
<style>
.od-UserFeedback-button {
background : #yourcolorcode ! important;
}
</style>
```

Comment: I don't happen to find the File Name in the Developer Tools for Internet Explorer.

Comment: Please see the Screenshot in my updated post. There is no File Name in Internet Explorer.

Comment: are you using a custom CSS file , or this default CSS file , second to check are you tried to scroll down till get file path at style section ? third thing why you don't try to apply this style without editing css <style>
.od-UserFeedback-button {
background : #yourcolorcode ! important;
}
</style>

Comment: also what's this page contain  specifically to can I open it from my side and check it ?!